# Data description on the fly using CKAN/Python

Tags: python, forms, upload, ckan

I wish to access the data found in a resource that a user has uploaded (i.e. after they have clicked on the 'upload' button and the user is idle) in CKAN, generate a list of the attribute names in the data using Python and relevant modules, and use the generated list to develop HTML drop-down lists to allow the user to map their data attribute names to my data attribute names which are collected from a PSQL database.

This sounds like a plugin but from my preliminary research I didn't find any which could help.

Does this sound like a viable project?

Any rough blueprints of efficient strategy to go about it?

Comment: What kind of data are you uploading? The combination of the datastore (parsing data into columns for a database) and some of the visualization extensions that let you choose columns sound related to me.

Comment: The datastore plugin did not cross my mind because it is not enabled in the production CKAN instance. However if it works it may save a lot of development time. Enabling it in our development environment should be straightforward though.

The uploaded data are of type vector which are usually contributed by the users in ERSI Shapes or OGC Services (i.e. WFS). I assume that the datastore is working quite well with the PostGIS extension enabled?

Which visualization extensions do you have in mind?

Edit: The ESRI Shapes are contributed within *.zip files.